# How to transform a dataframe to get only those records in output only when transaction happens

Tags: sql, apache-spark

There is one input dataframe with Name, transaction date and amount. Here we need to retrieve only those those records where there is transaction happened using pyspark dataframe.

Input -

```
Name| transaction_date |amount
Raju 15-Jan-2022 1000
Raju 16-Jan-2022 1000
Raju 17-Jan-2022 1500
```

Output

```
Name |transaction_date |amount
Raju 15-Jan-2022 1000
Raju 17-Jan-2022 1500
```

Comment: how do you define a transaction has happened ?

Comment: Based on the amount credited or debited

Comment: I think you did forget to fill in the amount column.

Comment: How do u define a credit or a debit , the flag is missing

Comment: Just by seeing the amount. If it is increased it was credit transaction otherwise debit

Answer (score 0):

[Window functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-window.html) to the rescue. Use `lag` to get previous record's balance for comparison.

```
SELECT Name, transaction_date, amount
  FROM (SELECT Name, transaction_date, amount,
               lag(amount, 1) over (partition by Name order by transaction_date) as previous_amount
          FROM df) as x
 WHERE amount != previous_amount;
```